# Terminological issues with Linear Transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, soft-question, linear-transformations, terminology

I have a question that is somewhat limited to terminology.

The definition I typically encountered of linear transformation (alternatively, linear operator) is that a linear transformation is a function $T : X \to Y$ with $X$ and $Y$ linear spaces that satisfies $T (\alpha x + y) = \alpha T (x) + T(y)$ for every $x, y \in X$ and $\alpha \in \Re$.

Is correct that actually the expression "linear transformation" is typically used also for functions whose domain $D \subseteq X$ and codomain $C \subseteq Y$ are simply *subsets* of linear spaces $X$ and $Y$ (e.g., convex subsets), without being necessarily linear subspaces?

Any feedback will be most welcome.

Comment: I think it is usually implied that the domain is a linear space, which implies that the image is also a linear space. In the theory of topological vector spaces, one encounters frequently operators that are defined on a subspace of $X$, often a dense subspace.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. In some cases it seems to me the objects are just neither linear spaces, nor subspaces of linear spaces. Thus, I wanted to get a confirmation of this feeling.

Comment: The objects are always linear spaces BUT you might be interested only in the restriction of the linear transformation to a subset of its domain, and you might choose to call this function on the subset a linear transformation, and no harm is done.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Thanks a lot, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think that, when you say that a linear transformation is some function $T\colon D\subset X\to C\subset Y$ that satisfies $T(\alpha x + y) = \alpha Tx + Ty$ for **every** $x, y\in D$ and $\alpha\in\mathfrak{R}$, you're assuming that $\alpha x + y$ belongs to $D$ for every $x, y$ and $\alpha$, i.e. $D$ is a subspace, and because the image of a linear transformation is a subspace of $Y$, there is no point of looking to a codomain $C$ that isn't at least a subspace as well.